# C programming: '&' with arrays in scanf

Tags: c

I got a warning in my program, and it says:

> `format '%c' expects argument of type 'char *' , but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[10]' [-Wformat]`

Here's my program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char array[10];
  scanf("%10c", &array);
  printf("%.10s", array);
  return 0;
}
```

The warning disappears when I remove '&' from scanf.
I know, it's an array and doesn't require &. But don't they have same effect?
I mean both '&array' and 'array' give address of its first element, right?
If so, what's the difference here?

I read some related questions here, and googled a lot.
It has been said that '&array' is a pointer to an array of characters if 'array' is an array while 'array' itself is a pointer to char.
According to what it says, since I'm using %c, a pointer to an array of characters should be passed, I think.
Idk, I would very greatful if someone explains how %[width]c works.

I also verified that all 'array', '&array' and '&array[0]' give address of its first element.
Here's what I did:

```
int main()
{
  char array[10];
  puts("ADDRESS:");
  printf(" %p \n %p \n %p", array, &array, &array[0]);
  return 0;
}
```

If they all give same address, why is it giving such warnings?
It also works for %s.
They all work fine in most of windows compiler, without any warnings.

Since I'm a windows user, I never used gcc compiler before. And what I was thinking was it's just not mandatory to write & as with function pointers.
You don't necessarily have to write & with function pointers, I read.

I'm getting more and more confused, please help me get it.

Thank you.

Comment: @ruakh
Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 4):

`array` and `&array` both yield a pointer to the same address, but with different types.  The former is equivalent in most situations to `&array[0]`, a `char *` in your case.  `&array`, however, is the address of the array itself, which has type `char (*)[10]` in your example.

Comment: Doesn't char(*)[10] mean an array of pointers with 10 elements?
Thanks for your answer, but may be that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: No, `char (*)[10]` is a pointer to an array of 10 `char`s.

Comment: Can you please explain how %[width]c work?
And, please show me a simple program using a pointer to an array of char, if possible.
That will be very useful.

Comment: Pointers to arrays are rarely used.

Answer (score 1):

array and &array are not the same... even if they have same address location in it.

array here being char array, it points to a single char, and if you increment it increases by 1 char size.

but &array points to the entire array and if increments it increases by the array size.

scanf function expects for the array.. not &array